# Is there a way to integrate facebook & google login in ionic PWA

Tags: facebook, angular, typescript, google-plus, ionic3

I developed an app in ionic 3. It's working fine for android & iOS. Then I added browser platform but fb & google login not working for it.

Ionic documentation http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/ says facebook plugin is supported in browser. But it's not working.

Google plus plugin only supports android & iOS.

So how to integrate fb & google login in PWA developed in ionic 3?

I have tried using angular4-social-login module but no luck. Also I tried using javascript sdk but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Facebook with Browser:**

After you add the `browser platform`:

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
ionic cordova build browser --prod
```

After that in your facebook develop website `settings page`, add your `server's domain to app domain` (or `localhost` for testing).

[image]

You can read more about it here: [**browser**](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/browser/README.md)

Comment: Getting this issue Refused to display <url> in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Comment: Actually it wasn't App domains. In OAuth redirect URLs, I mentioned localhost & it worked. Thanks for help @sampath. Please also help in google login.

Comment: This must work.Try that: https://github.com/abacritt/angular4-social-login

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)